# How to filter Azure Storage Logs?

Tags: .net, logging

[image]

Hi,

Here is the log I would like to filter.
By reading the documentation from Microsoft:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?view=aspnetcore-6.0

> "Logging": {
> "LogLevel": { // No provider, LogLevel applies to all the enabled providers.
> "Default": "Error",
> "Microsoft": "Warning",
> "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Warning"
> },  }

I thought that adding this, I should be able to filter logs, but It doesn't work

> "Azure.Core" : "Warning"

How to filter Azure Storage logs?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the appsettings, I finished to configure it in the code by adding:

```
.ConfigureLogging((hostContext, configLogging) => {
   configLogging.AddFilter("Azure.Core", LogLevel.Warning);
}
```